# Difference between console.log enabled verification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen `jquery-ui-1.8.11.js` verify `console.log` functionality by doing

```
if (this.debug)
   console.log()
```

I have also seen people define an anonymous function that is a no-op for browsers with no console logging like IE7.

```
if(typeof console === "undefined") {
    console = { log: function() { } };
}
```

---

Is there a technical difference or are both functionally equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those do something else. The first code suppresses logging messages unless a flag is set. The people who develop jQuery UI need logging when working on it, and turn it on. But people using the library don't want to have their console cluttered by log messages from libraries, so it's off by default. It lets you turn off logging even when the browser supports it – that regular users on IE7 don't get script errors is a (possibly intended) side effect.

The second code defines a dummy console.log(), so you can call the method without checking if it exists everywhere. It will not suppress logging on browsers where it's supported.

Comment: Ok, so they really are very different.  Thats what I need to know.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you've given, `this.debug` will be a reference to a `debug` variable in the jQueryUI code. This debug variable will have been set elsewhere, possibly by checking whether `console` is defined, but also possibly with other settings.

In any case, the first example is specific to the application; if you want to do a generic check to see whether the console is available, you'll need to use the second technique. You don't have to define an empty `console` object as per the example, but doing it that way does mean that you won't have to do the `if()` condition every time you want to call `console.log()`.

Having said all of that, I would counsel you strongly to avoid putting any code into production which contains calls to the `console`. The console should only be used for debugging purposes while you are working on the code. It should not be necessary in final release, and doing so can be a sign that either your code is unstable or you're unconfident of it, neither of which is a good sign if you're releasing the code for live use.

(libraries such as jQueryUI are an exception to this rule, as they need to provide functionality for developers to do debugging while writing code using their library)

Comment: "[leaving console.log() statements in] can be a sign that either your code is unstable or you're unconfident of it, neither of which is a good sign if you're releasing the code for live use." – I'm not sure how logging in your code is a sign of anything besides that you've at some point needed / wanted logging in your code. Stripping the log calls is still useful to reduce the download size, but I'd argue pretty much everyone who cares enough to look at JavaScript source code knows any code released has at some point in the past had bugs that needed diagnosing.

Answer (score -1):

The second of the two is standalone, not relying on jQuery. In my opinion, that makes it better.